# Move wordpress posts of custom post type with its categories along with child parent relationship of categories

Tags: php, database, wordpress, categories

I have been working on project of `wordpress` with my custom designed theme for a client. I provided my client two versions of his website, like one is `live` and other one is `staging`.

`Live` project is on for public while `staging` is for only client to see the required changes he want me to do.. if he is satisfied with the results I moved these changes to `live` project.

Now the problem I am facing now, is moving a data from `staging` to `live`.
Client had some data entry work on `staging` on a custom post type and assigned them categories and categories are in child parent relationship.

when I export custom post type, `wordpress` actually generates a file of `xml` in which all the `posts` and `categories` are available but there is no any child parent relationship.

I am posting below some pictures with a hope you can get a clear picture of my question and able to help/guide me.

Categories and its hierarchical order:
[image]

Result of export file: (xml file)
[image]
Note: `booklet-lvl-vi-sub-i` is a child category and a parent but export file does not seems to have any kind of relationship of categories.

Now this is when I am trying to import exported file its showing no any hierarchy.
[image]

I have tried many plugins to move data accurately and with its hierarchy order but found no success. I am really very confused now what to do and how to do that.

Please help/guide me through this problem, I have done my best to explain my situation, and hope you got this.. I really need the solution!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After taking a long break, finally I found the solution,

1. Exported all content from `Wordpress`

where I got all the data (Post/Categories/Tags) etc and `Categories` with child parent relationship.

2. Exported custom post type separatly (Optional)

I removed all the data from `xml` file from 1st step except `Categories` with child parent relationship and then merged with 2nd export file. Finally I have now a new `xml` file ready to be imported and I got what I needed.

Now I have all the posts with there `categories` having same child parent relationship.

Hope if anyone faces similar problem then my answer could help!